# Como puedo mejorar el código de RowSorter en java

Tags: java

En mi aplicación de Swing java, en todas mis tablas tengo un código similar al siguiente:

```
private DefaultTableModel modeloM;
private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter;

public frm_BuscarMateriales(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    
    //Asignar modelo y sorter para filtrar datos
    modeloM = (DefaultTableModel) jt_Materiales.getModel();
    filtroTabla();
}

private void filtroTabla()
{
    jt_Materiales.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modeloM);
    jt_Materiales.setRowSorter(sorter);
}

//Evento de textbox
private void txt_BuscarKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + txt_Buscar.getText(), 1));
}
```

Y funciona bastante bien, sin embargo he notado que algunas veces omite algunos registros cuando se ejecuta el filtrado, como puedo mejorar el código, o en su defecto hay alguna otra solución para que el filtrado pueda mejorar?